# Identify empty JSON files with Spark 2.4

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to avoid processing empty JSON files. Some empty JSON files I am getting only contain the open and close square brackets, like: `[]` . Files containing only that should be understood as empty files.

With Spark 2.2 the following line would return true:

`spark.read.json(pathToFile).isEmpty`

But with Spark 2.4 it returns false.

How do I go about identifying this type of file as empty when using Spark 2.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at columns

```
val stuff = spark.read.json("hdfs:///user/me/empty.json")

scala> stuff.columns
res6: Array[String] = Array()
```

Comment: Good point! Thanks! I have left it like this:
`spark.read.json(pathToFile).columns.isEmpty`